# Actualizar página después de la notificación de sonido

Tags: jquery

Tengo un sistema donde cuando llega un nuevo pedido emite una notificación sonora.

```
<audio id="notificacao" preload="auto">
  <source src="https://adm.site.co/sistema/alerta.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() { 
 function toque() {
    $.get("https://adm.site.com/sistema/atualizar.php", function (result) { 
        if(result == 1){
          $('#notificacao').trigger('play');
        }     
    });
  }   
toque();
setInterval(toque, 3000);    
});
</script>
```

Pero me gustaría que la página se actualice. Intenté incluir location.reload();, pero cuando lo hago, la notificación de sonido no funciona.

```
<audio id="notificacao" preload="auto">
  <source src="https://adm.site.co/sistema/alerta.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() { 
 function toque() {
    $.get("https://adm.site.com/sistema/atualizar.php", function (result) { 
        if(result == 1){
          $('#notificacao').trigger('play');
          location.reload();
        }     
    });
  }   
toque();
setInterval(toque, 3000);    
});
</script>
```

He probado de esa manera y tampoco funciona.

```
<audio id="notificacao" preload="auto">
  <source src="https://adm.site.co/sistema/alerta.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() { 
 function toque() {
    $.get("https://adm.site.com/sistema/atualizar.php", function (result) { 
        if(result == 1){
          if($('#notificação').trigger('play')){
            location.reload();
          }
        }     
    });
  }   
toque();
setInterval(toque, 3000);    
});
</script>
```

He usado otros comandos como history.go(0), la página se actualiza pero la notificación de sonido deja de funcionar. ¿Cómo puedo arreglar esto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si simplemente requiere de recargar la página actual al terminar el audio, se necesita de la función `ended` del audio.

Esto es lo que entendí: se debe recargar la página al terminar de sonar el audio.

```
const fin = $("#notificacao");
    
fin.on("ended", function() {   
    location.reload()
});
```

```
$("audio").on("ended", function() {   
    location.reload()
});
```

Comment: Funcionó. Muchas gracias Narciso.